# dbeaver table editing is blocked, what should I do?

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

[image]

You cannot edit the data in the table.

Field names are marked as locked.

How do I solve this?

DB : ORACLE

Answer (score 14):

try to refresh the database connection. It worked for me, I couldn't insert rows after creating the table.

Comment: This should be the right answer.

Comment: The `Invalidate/Reconnect` button wasn't enough for me. I had to click Disconnect and then connect again.

Comment: right answer indeed ..

Answer (score 1):

Never used `dbeaver` myself... after a little googling found this forum

post: https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=621

Though, this is an old post it mentions that:

> DBeaver can edit table only if it has at least one unique key or index

and also

regarding oracle pseudo columns like `rowid`

> for now DBeaver doesn't support "hidden" pseudocolumn at all

So, could you check if you can edit tables with unique key?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the connection will solve the issue. However if DBeaver shows

> Datasource was invalidated Live connection count: */*

Then disconnect the db from DBeaver and reconnect again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your query has any errors. For example an IN condition with a missing comma separator.

It can work by providing you the query result but can't be modified.